# nordVPN leak DNS test faild

Tags: networking, dns, vpn, openvpn

Since world is going to end soon [again =)] i got my self good deal at nordVPN. Just to be secure...
Install openVPN and done settings as it say's on nordVPN web-site. 
- Ubuntu [ budgie ]

I run few DNS leak and it found my default DNS and an DNS that i load-file in connection. I try few servers and all of them are founded.

> At my smartphone is ok. With APP i connect to any server and run
>   multiple test and only app-selected server is found.

I edit my reslov.conf

```
nameserver 78.46.223.24

nameserver 162.242.211.137
```

[ from nordVPN article ]

Just to say. My router is SIM card based 3g/4g internet.

At first live support they say that might my router leak original DNS. And i can't stay to that since my smartphone connected to that router don't leak an DNS. Also without wifi, smartphone with his own 4g don't leak any DNS.

So i thinking is there any possible that any program that can leak DNS to internet. Any way to find it and fix so i can use it with secure ?

Do i missing anything ?

If someone can share words of wisdom or give some points of useful article  how to set it up...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and PavelRyzhov's solution in this link helped me solve it: https://askubuntu.com/a/949272/311570

To copy his current solution:

> In order to let `openvpn` to alter the system DNS settings, therefore
>   eliminating the leak, add the following lines at the end of the your
>   `*.ovpn` configuration file:
>
> ```
> script-security 2
> up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
> down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
> ```

Details of what this does are included in his post.